# Make a regex shorter

Tags: regex, vba

Iam using regex in vba to filter some data from a textfile.
The textfile looks like this:

```
GB01;150.08 ;0.00 ;1000.48 ;800.40 ;1000.48 ;1000.48 ;201304
AB01;150.08 ;0.00 ;1000.48 ;800.40 ;1000.48 ;1000.48 ;201304
CB01;150.08 ;0.00 ;1000.48 ;800.40 ;1000.48 ;1000.48 ;201304
```

I want to filer everything so my regex looks like this:

```
(\w+);(\d+.?\d+)\s;(\d+.?\d+)\s;(\d+.?\d+)\s;(\d+.?\d+)\s;(\d+.?\d+)\s;(\d+.?\d+)\s;(\d+)
```

Im very new to regex so im limited with what i can do.
Is there a way to make this regex shorter and more clean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you only want to split those lines in this?

GB01

150.08

0.00

1000.48

800.40

1000.48

1000.48

201304

You can try Split method, maybe will be useful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Yeah i want to filter everything from a txt, then save the values in a variable, make some maths with the numbers and put the result in a table in the right place. So yeah i think the splitmethod will work, thank you!

Comment: If the answer helps you, please check as correct one ;) Will be useful for eveyone! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use repetition on the group matching the (numbers + space + ';'):

```
(\w+);(\d+\.?\d+ ;)+
```

Note that the second group matches the last number as well, without the ';'